# How to verify if all nested items contain the same key in a multidimensional PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, key, verify

I have this array in php:

```
[
    {
        "idespecialidad": "001",
        "especialidad": "ALBAÑIL",
        "cantidad": "3",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "11.9"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "006",
        "especialidad": "CHEF",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "5.3"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "003",
        "especialidad": "ELECTRICISTA",
        "cantidad": "2",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "7.7"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "009",
        "especialidad": "PROGRAMADOR",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE"
    }
]
```

I need to verify if each object has the same keys (for e.g. in this case the last one doesn't have `distancia` ), then return **true** or **false**.

**Edit:** I tried this:

```
if (array_key_exists('distancia', $array)) {
   echo json_encode($array);
} else {
    echo "a null json";
}
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What about `foreach`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% clear on what you wish to do with the data, but the two options I believe will work best for you are [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) and [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php).

First, set the basic JSON example as a string:

```
//  Set the JSON string for this example.
$json_string = <<<EOT
[
    {
        "idespecialidad": "001",
        "especialidad": "ALBAÑIL",
        "cantidad": "3",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "11.9"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "006",
        "especialidad": "CHEF",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "5.3"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "003",
        "especialidad": "ELECTRICISTA",
        "cantidad": "2",
        "codpais": "PE",
        "distancia": "7.7"
    },
    {
        "idespecialidad": "009",
        "especialidad": "PROGRAMADOR",
        "cantidad": "1",
        "codpais": "PE"
    }
]
EOT;
```

Now an example that uses [`array_map`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php):

```
// Decode the JSON string as any array.
$json_string_decoded = json_decode($json_string, true);

// Use array_map to return an array telling you what items have 'distancia'.
$contains_distancia = array_map(function($value) {
    return array_key_exists('distancia', $value);
  }, $json_string_decoded);

// Dump the array to view the contents.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($contains_distancia);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be a new array called `$contains_distancia` which returns true or false based on which items in the main array contain `distancia`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 1
    [3] => 
)
```

But I just saw in another answer you ask:

> But, what happend if i want to return a `format json` just with the
>   objects which have de distancia key?

Easy, just use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like this example:

```
// Decode the JSON string as any array.
$json_string_decoded = json_decode($json_string, true);

// Filter the array with 'array_filter'.
$contains_distancia = array_filter($json_string_decoded, function($value) {
    return array_key_exists('distancia', $value);
  });

// Dump the array to view the contents.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($contains_distancia);
echo '</pre>';
```

The returned array `$contains_distancia` would be just the items with `distancia`:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [idespecialidad] => 001
            [especialidad] => ALBAÃ‘IL
            [cantidad] => 3
            [codpais] => PE
            [distancia] => 11.9
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [idespecialidad] => 006
            [especialidad] => CHEF
            [cantidad] => 1
            [codpais] => PE
            [distancia] => 5.3
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [idespecialidad] => 003
            [especialidad] => ELECTRICISTA
            [cantidad] => 2
            [codpais] => PE
            [distancia] => 7.7
        )

)
```

Then just use [`json_encode`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) like this on `$contains_distancia`:

```
// Decode the JSON string as any array.
$json_string_decoded = json_decode($json_string, true);

// Convert the array to JSON.
$contains_distancia_json = json_encode($contains_distancia);

// Dump the json to view the contents.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($contains_distancia_json);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output would be:

```
[{"idespecialidad":"001","especialidad":"ALBA\u00d1IL","cantidad":"3","codpais":"PE","distancia":"11.9"},{"idespecialidad":"006","especialidad":"CHEF","cantidad":"1","codpais":"PE","distancia":"5.3"},{"idespecialidad":"003","especialidad":"ELECTRICISTA","cantidad":"2","codpais":"PE","distancia":"7.7"}]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just check if the first item's keys against every other element.

```
function has_same_keys($arr)
{
    $keys = array_keys($arr[0]);
    for ($i = 1; $i < count($arr); $i++) {
        if ($keys <> array_keys($arr[$i])) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

To get the list of objects that have key `distancia` in json.

```
$filtered = array();
foreach ($arr1 as $x) {
    if (isset($x['distancia'])) {
        $filtered[] = $x;
    }
}
$json_string = json_encode($filtered);
```

Comment: Nice, thank you. But, what happend if i want to return a `format json` just with the objects which have de `distancia` key ?